# Eclipse Tomcat not Updating

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, tomcat, hotdeploy

I am developing an application with SpringMVC and Tomcat using Eclipse. The problem is: the server does not update the changes I am making.

One example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView test(){

        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("test");                 
        System.out.println("test");
        return mv;
    }
```

Every time I hit the mapped url, Eclipse prints test in my console. If I comment out the `println`, I get the same result.

Attempts to fix the problem:

- clean Tomcat directory
- restart the server
- close Eclipse
- add/remove the project in the Server tab
- delete the JSP the method is using
- different browsers

All to no effect. It just looks like Tomcat is not updating any changes I make in the code.

Comment: Ideally, you are not running maven install which deletes the contents of the target folder.

Comment: So i should do a maven install everytime i change the code?

Comment: did you configure eclipse to build your project automatically ? (menu "project") did you configure your tomcat server instance to publish on change (double click on tomcat server to see "publish" section) ? is there any pending error on your project ("problems" view) ?

Comment: Yes, yes publishing, no errors, the project was updating fine a few days ago

Comment: have u tried restarting the system. I have also faced the same issue in past, and gets resolved after restarting. I think this issue comes when we open so many files in eclipse paralley

Comment: Yes...u shud do maven install.

Answer (score 12):

To make Eclipse Tomcat update automatically or hot deploy you have to make certain changes in server configuration:

Below are the steps:

1. Double clicks on the **`Tomcat Server`**, refer to **`"publishing"`** tab in the **`"Overview"`** view, make sure **`"Automatically publish when resources change"`** is selected. This should be the default option, to support **`“hot deploy”`** resources, for example : JSP, XML and properties files.
2. In the Tomcat Plugin page, click on the **`"Modules"`** view, Select the Module then click on Edit button and make sure **`"Auto Reload"`** is **`"Disabled"`**. Default is enabled.
3. Start Project in **`DEBUG`** mode. Hot Deploy is supported in DEBUG mode only.

Comment: Yeah, all the setting are already like that, the project was working fine last week

Comment: As @MauroM says, it was working fine last week for me too. But launching the server in debug seems to fix it. It stopped working without touching it. Why? :C

Comment: For a more visual guide, see: http://www.mkyong.com/eclipse/how-to-configure-hot-deploy-in-eclipse/

Answer (score 2):

Two more things to check:

- **deploy directory**: in the tomcat server UI and according to "deploy path" configuration, check that the output directory has read/write access (you could also remove it and try to publish again : check expected output resources/classes).
- **deployment assembly**: in project properties menu; in the "deployment assembly" section, check that you are publishing all wanted resources. For example, in my case I download/generate some items from maven custom plugin phase and this resources are not published by default. I had to add some target subdirectories here...

Comment: Adding some target subdirectories did the trick for me.  Thank @boly38.

Answer (score 0):

I had roughly the same problem and after tried it all with no success I gave up, created  another fresh workspace and the problem was gone. Not the ideal solution but hey, it's an option.